# A simple and obvious looking inequality but difficult to prove.

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n$ are n positive integers and $m\in\mathbb R\setminus(0,1)$, then, $$\frac{a_1^m+a_2^m+\dots+a_n^m}{n}\geq\left[\frac{a_1+a_2+...+a_n}n\right]^m.$$ 
I tried to prove it using am-gm inequality and contradiction but I didn't reach to the conclusion.

Comment: hint: $x^m$ is a convex function

Comment: It was unclear what you meant for the range if $m,$ but I took a guess.

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean#Proof_of_power_means_inequality).

Comment: use Jensen inequality

Comment: Thank you Dr Zafar Ahmed sir for giving me a detailed solution. Also thank you Thomas sir for editing my question. Also thank you Athos sir and Taha direk sir for giving me hint.

Answer (score 0):

Let $$F(x)=x^m, x>0 \Rightarrow F''m(m-1)x^{m-2} >0 ~if~  m<0 ~ or ~ m>1$$
Sot the curvature is positive, then by Jemsen's inequality we get
$$\frac{f(a_1)+f(a_2)+f(a_3)+....+f(a_n)}{n} \ge \left(\frac{a_1+a_2+a_3+...+a_n}{n}\right)^m.$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{a_1^m+a_2^m+a_3^m+...+a_n^2}{n} \ge \left( \frac{a_1+a_2+a_3+..a_n}{n} \right)^m, ~if~ m<0~ or ~m>1.$$
But if $0<m<1$, the sign of inequality reverses. For m=0,1, equality holds

Comment: Thank you sir for providing me detailed solution. I read about Jensen's inequality and also about its proof. I wanted to ask whether Jensen's inequality can also be proved without using mathematical induction.